# jQuery loop through multipdimensional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, each

I have a 2d array in a PHP file called `$array`, with the columns `id`, `msg` and `timestamp`

A multidimensional array is then created, and output as a JSON from an AJAX call:

```
$ok = 1;
$error = null;

echo JSON_ENCODE(array('ok'=>$ok, 'err'=>$error, 'arr'=>$array));
```

I am trying to loop through the nested array called `arr`, this I cannot figure out, what I have tried:

```
$.each(data,function(i,index){
    $('#msg_apnd').append(data[index].midt + data[index].msg);
});
```

This only loops through the data array, and therefore only the one row, when I need it to loop through the nested `arr` array, so i tried this:

```
$.each(data,function(i,index){
    $.each(i,function(i2,index2){
        $('#msg_apnd').append(arr[index].midt + arr[index].msg);
    });
});
```

I'm a little stuck and haven't been able to find a suitable answer elsewhere. I need the jQuery code to loop through the nested `arr` array in the AJAX response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the `.arr` using a member operator because `data` is an object

```
$.each(data.arr,function(idx, val){
        $('#msg_apnd').append(val.midt + val.msg);
});
```

Also [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) callback receives the index of the current item as the first argument and the current item as the second argument

Answer (score 0):

The success callback should be like below:

```
function (response) {
  console.log(response.ok, response.err, response.arr);
  $.each(response.arr, function(i, v){
    $('#msg_apnd').append(v.midt + v.msg);
  });
}
```